# Помогите с авторизацией на сайте

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Мне понадобилась авторизация на сайте https://store.bezlimit.ru/app/login

но она не зароботала.

код:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
page = s.post('https://store.bezlimit.ru/app/login', data= {'LoginForm[login]': '49492','LoginForm[password]': 'h2f',}, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 YaBrowser/20.9.1.110 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'})
print(page.text)
```

результат роботы кода:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
    <head>
    <title>Bad Request (#400)</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=1600239982" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf-auth">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="HqVzNdAOpHLlSA2K-4RqultAppLNOdX_EJXNF2hy5B9oyyt7uHeJF7MPVMHP3TDrDBnW9qZ3p55ipZ9CLjqBew==">
    <link href="/css/style.css?v=1598609110" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/custom.css?v=1601305783" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/loader.css?v=1579513251" rel="stylesheet">    <meta name="theme-color" content="#814197">
</head>            <body>
            <div class="layout">
                <div class="layout__content">
                    <div class="header layout__header" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="550">
    <div class="header__top">
        <div class="header__logo-container">
            <a class="header__logo" href="/"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="header__section-container">
            <h1 class="h1">Bad Request (#400)</h1>
                    </div>
    </div>
</div>                                                            <section class="content">
    <div class="error-page">
        <img src="/img/error-emoji.png" alt="">        <div class="error-content">
            <h3>Bad Request (#400)</h3>
            <p>Не удалось проверить переданные данные.</p><br/>
            <p><a class="link" href="/">На главную</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    <script src="/assets/c1ec8854/jquery.js?v=1588632646"></script>
<script src="/assets/94bbd99f/yii.js?v=1600120330"></script>
<script src="/assets/d0f8c98f/js/bootstrap.js?v=1550073338"></script>
<script src="/js/analytics/metrika.js?v=1567538190"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js?v=1563268397"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/jquery.scrollTo.min.js?v=1535189531"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js?v=1535189531"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/clipboard.min.js?v=1560261272"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/jquery.countdown.min.js?v=1571850546"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/jquery.cookie.js?v=1594063262"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js?v=1602230915"></script></html>


Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите в чём моя ошибка

Comment: Вы не передаёте CSRF-токен.

Comment: а где его найти и как передать